# AddEventListener Firing Twice

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an event listener on a button that opens up a form HTML, and when you click the form button, it successfully works and adds one book. But if you click on the add book button again, open the form, and click the form button, it will add two books, calling the addNewBook func twice.

I tried looking at the debugger, and that's what I found, it's showing that it's calling twice, but I need to see how.

```
const bookBtn = document.querySelector(".book-btn");
const bookContainer = document.querySelector(".book-container");
const formContainer = document.querySelector(".form-container");

const addNewBook = (book, author, pages, read) => {
  const bookDiv = document.createElement("div");
  bookDiv.classList.add("book");

  console.log(book.value, author.value, pages.value, read.value);

  const h3 = document.createElement("h3");
  h3.textContent = book.value;
  const p1 = document.createElement("p");
  p1.textContent = author.value;
  const p2 = document.createElement("p");
  p2.textContent = pages.value;
  const p3 = document.createElement("p");
  p3.textContent = read.value;
  const childElements = [h3, p1, p2, p3];
  for (let i = 0; i < childElements.length; i++) {
    bookDiv.appendChild(childElements[i]);
  }
  bookContainer.appendChild(bookDiv);
  formContainer.style.display = "none";
};

bookBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  formContainer.style.display = "block";
  const addButton = document.querySelector(".form-btn");
  addButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    debugger;
    const book = document.querySelector("#name");
    const author = document.querySelector("#author");
    const pages = document.querySelector("#pages");
    const read = document.querySelector("#read");
    addNewBook(book, author, pages, read);
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't add event listeners inside event listeners. Every time the outer one triggers, it adds a new, duplicate listener. Simply move the `addButton` code out of the `bookBtn` listener

Answer (score 3):

You're adding an event listener to the `addButton` here:

```
bookBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  formContainer.style.display = "block";
  const addButton = document.querySelector(".form-btn");
  addButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
```

and that last line runs *every time* the `bookBtn` is clicked.

Ideally, don't add that listener conditionally. Add it only once, and have the `bookBtn` only show the form rather than doing anything else.

```
bookBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  formContainer.style.display = "block";
});
const addButton = document.querySelector(".form-btn");
addButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const book = document.querySelector("#name");
  const author = document.querySelector("#author");
  const pages = document.querySelector("#pages");
  const read = document.querySelector("#read");
  addNewBook(book, author, pages, read);
});
```

If you require that the button there does nothing until the `bookBtn` is clicked once, add a boolean flag to indicate whether there's been a click yet.

```
let clicked = false;
bookBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  formContainer.style.display = "block";
  clicked = true;
});

const addButton = document.querySelector(".form-btn");
addButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!clicked) return;
  const book = document.querySelector("#name");
  const author = document.querySelector("#author");
  const pages = document.querySelector("#pages");
  const read = document.querySelector("#read");
  addNewBook(book, author, pages, read);
});
```